# NSPredicate subquery for multiple arguments

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using NSPredicate for filtering out CoreData elements.

```
[predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(properties, $x, $x.type IN %@ AND $x.val CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0)", @[@"first_name",@"last_name", @"organization"], searchString]];
```

In general I want to return only elements that has one of type (first_name, last_name, organization) and value which contains a given string. I'm using it to filter out contacts during search mode.

Problem is that I don't know what is best solution to handle search when user typed in search string with spaces, for example:

"firstName lastName"

In that case I would like to return  a properties that has both "firstName" and "lastName" in any of those properties.

I'm thinking about adding a predicate for each component I get from:

```
[searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]
```

and make AND between them, but maybe there is an easier way to pass an array to predicate so it takes all values from it.

Comment: Do you need the CONTAINS check or would a check for equality be sufficient?

Comment: I need CONTAINS, equal is not gonna be too good for user experience